# Gradle war fails with compile task

Tags: java, spring, gradle

In order to set war file into Tomcat server, I try :

Gradle war (5.3.1)fails with

provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'

Could not find provided

Do you know why ?

Do not hesitate to merge request or commit at https://github.com/moueza/spring-mvc-hello-world-example-mkyong-gradle/issues/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no such `provided`configuration. There is `providedCompile` and `providedRuntime`. Read [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html#sec:war_dependency_management).

Comment: OK. Indeed, no in your provided documentation. But Maven gave me that command at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0 ? So how can I import HttpServletResponse dependency, for gradle war to compile ?

Comment: How about using `providedCompile`, as explained in the gradle documentation that I linked to?

Comment: providedCompile: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0' fails too !

Comment: You need to tell **how** it fails. But what you posted isn't valid. there shouldn't be a `:` after providedCompile

Comment: Ah yes, it is not same syntax as compile group:  .OK. Thank you